# Unknown user-based global PIP configuration sets wrong PyPi registry

Tags: python, pip

I used to need to install all PIP packages from a private repository (that mirrored pypi.org but also contained some of our own packages).

To ensure that `pip install <package>` would always resolve all packages from this repository, I created a file named `~/.pypirc` with this content:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = 
    nexus
    nexus-own

[nexus]
repository = https://nexus.REDACTED.com/repository/pypi/
username = REDACTED
password = REDACTED

[nexus-own]
repository = https://nexus.REDACTED.com/repository/our-pypi/
username = REDACTED
password = REDACTED
```

However, the process has now been changed and the specified repository doesn't exist any more.

I deleted the `.pypirc` file but still, pip will try to resolve packages from the private repository.

For my own projects I can circumvent this by explicitly stating pypi.org as repository in the `Pipfile`, but when I want to install a package globally, it will fail because it will try to access the now-defunct repository:

```
Looking in indexes: https://REDACTED:****@nexus.REDACTED.com/repository/pypi/simple
Collecting PACKAGE_NAME_REDACTED
  Downloading PACKAGE_NAME_REDACTED
     - 193.2 kB 2.7 MB/s 0:00:00
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file /private/var/folders/yg/c7k3cx_s105249_xfk0rz8vr0000gp/T/pip-unpack-pyy2dbxl/REDACTED.git (downloaded from /private/var/folders/yg/c7k3cx_s105249_xfk0rz8vr0000gp/T/pip-req-build-sqsbu7rx, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
```

How can this be now that the `.pypirc` file has been removed?

Does pip cache this information anywhere? I've searched my complete user's home directory recursively but could not find any trace of this configuration.

Where could pip be getting it from?

How can I make pip revert back to the default settings with pypi.org as default repository?

This only affects one user; if I login as a different user, I can install packages from pypi.org withouth problems.

My local system is macOS 13.2.1. Ventura.
Pip version is 22.3.1.
Python version is 3.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` doesn't consult with `.pypirc`, `twine` does when **uploading** packages.

`pip` when **downloading** consults with `pip.conf`. To list your configuration files run

```
pip config debug
```

See the docs at  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

Comment: Thanks. Now I remember why I hate to develop in Python - the language is great but the toolchain is a mess.

Comment: @ronin667 Every day I believe less and less the language is good (I have been using Python since version 1.4, 1996). How come people using such a great language created such bad tools? Do you really believe people who created these tools could create a great language?